# How to add a shift to tikz baseline.

Tags: tikz-pgf, baseline

I use the following code to draw a tikz image between some text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
calc
}

\begin{document}
Hello\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]\draw(0,0) circle (10pt);\LaTeX.
\end{document}
```

Then I want to add a little shift to it, for example

```
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.north)-5pt]\draw(0,0) circle (10pt);
```

But this have no effect. I also tried `yshift` or `transform canvas`, both does not work.

Does anyone know how to solve this? thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can add the shift by one of the following ways. Only the last one needs the `calc` library. In both cases you need to surround the coordinate with `{ }` to either mask the inner `[ ]` or `,`.

```
Hello\tikz[baseline={([yshift=-5pt]current bounding box.north)}]\draw(0,0) circle (10pt);\LaTeX.

Hello\tikz[baseline={($ (current bounding box.north) - (0,5pt) $)}]\draw(0,0) circle (10pt);\LaTeX.
```

Note that the `([<options>]coordinate)` style works also in general (so does the other one). If you want to shift from the center of a node you should explicitly reference the `center` anchor to avoid some possible issues. Without an anchor the special *border anchor* is used which seems to cause issues with shifts. With `baseline` there might be no problem, but for drawn lines there is.